# IMAGE() value as a formula isn't working

Tags: formula, images

I have a formula field, where I want to display a resource based on the user.
I Upload a small 25X25 image to static resources.
I than have a field on the user, which is the resource updated:

```
"/resource/1634210826000/UserLogo"
```

I have a formula field on the case, that shows the image:
NOTE: This option works, when the 'IMAGE' value is static.

```
IMAGE( "/resource/1634210826000/UserLogo" ,Owner:User.FirstName, 20, 20)
```

Since I want this to be correct for all users, I change the IMAGE value to be:

```
IMAGE( Owner:User.Case_Thumbnail__c  ,Owner:User.FirstName, 20, 20)
```

ALAS: This is not working, and the image isn't shown.

- I only replace the same value that I have on the user field, with the related formula field, and it's working, and vice versa - not working.

Any ideas?

The only explanation I have, is that IMAGE - can not interpret formula fields.

After some more testing, I believe that the IMG function can only read static data entered with '' // ""
I had a simple text field on the case that holds the thumbnail to use, but when rendering the IMG result, the SRC value is empty

[image]

I will open an issue with SF on this.

Comment: What does the rendered output look like? Maybe the URL is wrong?

Comment: if the value of `User.Case_Thumbnail__c` is `resource/1634210826000/UserLogo` (no double quotes) does it work?